# TextView with different font for substring? Only a substring within the TextView's text string is to be bold

Tags: android

I have a requirement to display text where only a substring is bold.  Is there anyway to format so that only that only the substring (a date field) is shown in bold and it also have a different text size?  I suppose I could use 3 TextViews and break this up but I would rather not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bold and italic tags in Android TextViews.  For more advanced formatting, you can just use [SpannableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) to build your formatted String.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the simple formatting you described probably you can use HTML tags to achieve it.

For example

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("sample <big>sample</big> <big><big><big><b>sample</b></big></big></big>"));
```